# How to subtract to previous year, but add months in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, functional-programming, procedural-programming, sql-date-functions

I am new to procedural programming and mysql, but suppose I have a function `PrevMonth(in_date date, in_mn_count int)` The first is a date and the second is an integer which is expected to be the number of months. The function returns a string with the format `'YYYY-MM'` which is the year and month, where the year in the first parameter is the previous year, and in_mn_count is added to in_date.

For example, `a_testbed.PrevMonth('2012-05-19', 6)` returns `'2011-11'`

This is what I have:

```
set return_date := Date_format(DATE_ADD(in_date, INTERVAL -1 YEAR),
DATE_ADD(in_date,    INTERVAL in_mn_count MONTH),'%Y %M');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues here, your format for DATE_FORMAT is wrong, and you are passing the date through DATE_ADD twice for some odd reason.

```
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(in_date, INTERVAL (in_mn_count-12) MONTH), '%Y-%m')
```

That would do the trick, because 12 months is 1 year.

Note the small 'm' in '%Y-%m', that is actually what you want if you desire '2011-05' type of return value.

Comment: I need to go to the previous year and add months to in_date. Where is the year subtracted in DATE_ADD to get to previous year?

Comment: How is that different to subtracting 12 months? Have you found the case where subtracting 12 months and subtracting 1 year yields different results?

Comment: So does -12 represent the year subtracted? That is what it seems.